# Debug COM dll from host application

Tags: com, debug-symbols

I have a COM dll that I would like to debug running from an external application, I'm sure this worked before but is not working any more. (using VS 2012 RC) I have read MANY articles but I have not seen one where it mentions using an external app, is this still possible?

I'm getting the 'debug symbols not loaded' message, when I go to Debug > Windows > Modules my dll is not listed but the external app is listed, is that correct?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Of course you cannot debug a DLL that isn't loaded.  Why the "external app" doesn't load your DLL is quite unclear, perhaps you ought to debug it.

Comment: Debugging external app unfortunately not an options, its an entire ERP...

Comment: Well, write your own "external app" then, a simple exe that doesn't do anything but load the DLL and call methods.  Think "unit test" here.

Comment: This was my only option left and it worked :(... Thanks for suggesting though :)

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using either an earlier version of MSVS (e.g. MSVS 2010 Pro), or downloading WinDbg.  Either one should easily do the job:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx
- http://therightstuff.de/2010/07/24/WinDbg-Commands.aspx

Comment: Thanks, will try this, looks like Greek though :)

Comment: After many attempts I could not get the tools to download (think its a Win8 issue), wrote a test app and got debugging, thanks for the tips though